# clangd installed via mason-lspconfig shows "Use of undeclared indentifier" for evreything

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, clangd, mason

Recently, I took on a C++ project involving 2D games. I started by setting up neovim with clangd LSP but upon opening the project, I encountered warning messages(alotough in red), such as "Use of undeclared identifier" and issues with libraries, like  "" file not being found. Despite these warnings, the project runs smoothly as intended using CMake.

I attempted to address these warnings by exploring the configurations in *lspconfig.clang.setup* but found no relevant solutions. Switching to Visual Studio Code, I observed a reduction in some of these warnings, but encountered different ones instead.

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question to provide any concrete suggestions. Please start with https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup, and pay attention in particular to generating a `compile_commands.json` file for the project. Also take a look at https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting. If you've done that, and are still having issues, please share [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) for further help.